# How do I generate the iOS folder in my react native project if I'm on windows?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

No matter what I try to do, I can't seem to generate the iOS folder for my project. I've tried `expo eject`, `react-native eject`, `react-native upgrade`, all to no avail. I managed to generate the android folder but not the iOS one. I think I read once that you need to be on a mac to generate an iOS folder, is this true? If so, can I move my project onto a mac, generate the folder there, and then move it back onto my windows computer?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Why do you need the iOS folder folder?
2. After ejecting you wont be able to use iOS on windows

Comment: I want to use react-native-push-notifications and for that I apparently need to install something in the iOS folder

Comment: Why not using Push Notification capabilities shipped with expo?

If eject the project you wont be able to compile/test iOS on a windows machine.

Comment: How do I do that? Are they local? I want to make sure these notifications are local and work on both iOS and android.

Comment: As you can see in expo docs https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/

Under Local notifications Platform Compatibility you can see expo probably offers the capabilities you need.

Comment: Thank you, I'll use that!